# Excel VBA How to Loop through children of a ClassName

Tags: excel, vba

First off I hope this hasn't been asked already.  I've searched extensively but may have missed the answer.  I'm a somewhat novice to VBA so please keep that in mind if this is a simple question.

I am creating a macro in Excel to parse HTML.

HTML Sample

```
<div class="person">
<div class="person name"><John Doe></div>
<div class="person level-1"></div>
<div class="person level-2"></div>
<div class="person level-3 invalid"></div>
</div>
<div class="person">
<div class="person name"><Bob Smith></div>
<div class="person level-1"></div>
<div class="person level-2 invalid"></div>
<div class="person level-3 invalid"></div>
</div>
```

** "person levelx has an "invalid" appended to it if that person has not yet reached that level.

I want to loop through the person class and find the highest 'person level' without invalid. So in this example I'd output 'person level-2' for John and 'person level-1' for Bob.

To date I've tried many different iterations but am completely stuck.  I imagine the code should be something like:

```
Dim person As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim persons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
set persons = document.getElementsByClassName("person")

PersonRowNum = 2
For each person in persons
    If person.getElementsByTagName("div") = "person level-2 invalid" Then
        Cells(PersonRowNum, 6) = "Person Level 1"
        PersonRowNum = PersonRowNum + 1
    Else
        If person.getattribute("classname") = "person level-3 invalid" Then
            Cells(PersonRowNum, 6) = "Person Level 2"
            PersonRowNum = PersonRowNum + 1
        Else
            Cells(PersonRowNum, 6) = "Person Level 3"
            PersonRowNum = PersonRowNum + 1
        End If
    End If
next person
```

My guess is there is some instruction to go to the next element in the collection but I can't get that to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to reveal the link of that site to get a quicker response?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a private site so the link would be no help.